# How to do Network Kernel Density Estimation Analysis in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, network-analyst, kernel-density

I am looking at doing some analysis of road traffic collisions. Obviously collisions occur on stretches of roads and I was researching the best methodology to take into account the network element of it. The usual hot-spotting (Kernel Density) smooths things out too much, and I found a few articles on Network Kernel Density Estimation which is supposed to be more representative as it calculates the distance between events via the network rather than using euclidean distances. We are using ArcGIS Basic/Standard 10 at the moment. We do not have Spatial Analyst licence but we have Crime Analyst and Network Analyst.

Anybody has done this before in ArcGIS? I've googled it I can't find any ready made tools - so I was wondering if anybody had a script I could use?  Or any idea on how I could do it in a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a set of add-on ArcGIS Desktop tools (versions 9- 10.2) using network kernel density techniques developed by Professor Okabe available here.  http://sanet.csis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/.

However they are only licensed for academic use.  I used them on my MSc thesis and they worked really well.  I guess you could enquire about commercial implementations.

According to the documentation there is an open source implementation in GRASS (v.kernel).